# Receiving a string in Java graphics from a text box

Tags: java, graphics

I started to make a graphic for program I built in which to insert a name and length of a song, how do I do it in graphics? I found out how to pick up a button but I do not understand how to absorb something inserted into a text box

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Active extends Frame {
public void init() {
    ActionListener al = new MyActionListener();
    TextField tf = new TextField(20);
    Button b;
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setSize(1000, 1000);
    b = new Button ("first");
    b.setActionCommand("First");
    b.addActionListener(al);
    add(b);
    b = new Button ("Second");
    b.setActionCommand("Second");
    b.addActionListener(al);
    add(b);
    setVisible(true);   
    add(tf);
}
public Active(String caption) {
    super(caption);
    init();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Active m = new Active("Active buttons");
}
}
```

the main:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String s = e.getActionCommand();
    if(s.equals("First")) {
        System.out.println("The first button was switched");
    }
    if(s.equals("Second")) {
        System.out.println("The second button was switched");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do *what* in Graphics? And what do you mean by doing it *in graphics*? Also, why are you using a GUI library, AWT, that is 2 generations out of date?

Comment: Not everyone's English is as refined as certain others and therefore we need to interpret what is actually asked within the post. If we **really** want to help we will make this effort to do that interpretation and make the necessary assumptions.  Reading the question I get: `I started to make a GUI for a program I wrote in which to insert a name and length of a song. How do I do it in a GUI? I found out how to catch a button event but I do not understand how to get the data typed in a JTextField.`. With this in mind: `String text = tf.getText();`. However, I could be wrong.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I would write it with the *Swing GUI Toolkit*. Here is a short example of that:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JTextField songNameField;
    private JTextField songLengthField;
    private JButton assignBtn;

    public MyPanel()
    {
        this.songNameField = new JTextField();
        this.songLengthField = new JTextField();
        this.assignBtn = new JButton("Assign");

        this.assignBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                String name = songNameField.getText();
                int length = Integer.parseInt(parsesongLengthField.getText());

                ...
            }
        });

        this.add(songNameField);
        this.add(songLengthField);
        this.add(assignBtn);
    }
}
```